# how to fit the text width in android canvas?

Tags: android, text, android-canvas

hi my application is draw the text in canvas its working fine.my problem while my text is large is goes outside of the canvas.

for example text=**"how are you"** its correctly fit into the canvas.but while text=**"hi hello how are you"**
like lenghthy text.it goes outside form the canvas.anybody kindly help me.Thanks in advance!

```
        canvas1.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas1.drawBitmap(resizeImage1,10,5, null);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        canvas1.drawText(mytext, 10,175, paint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Static layouts, it will take care of auto aligning your text even if you increase it by some limit, by auto aligning the text.

```
    Rect bounds = new Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2);// set the bounds
    String textOnCanvas = "text to be wriiten";
    StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(textOnCanvas, textPaint,
            bounds.width(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 1, true);
    canvas.save();
    float textHeight = getTextHeight(textOnCanvas, textPaint);
    int numberOfTextLines = sl.getLineCount();
    float textYCoordinate = bounds.exactCenterY() -
            ((numberOfTextLines * textHeight) / 2);

    //text will be drawn from left
    float textXCoordinate = bounds.left;
    canvas.translate(textXCoordinate, textYCoordinate);
    //draws static layout on canvas
    sl.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int IMAGE_WIDTH = text.length();
```

canvas1.drawBitmap(resizeImage1,IMAGE_WIDTH ,5, null);

Answer (score 0):

Very lickely that you are exceeding the width of the bitmap.

Each canvas has a bitmap associated with it, the width of the bitmap might be smaller than the width of the text.

So when you try to draw the text it is going beyond the boundary of the bitmap and hence you are not able to see the rest of the text.

Try increasing the size of the bitmap.

Comment: am adding image and text canvas,if i cange the bitmap size image is affected

Comment: You can reduce the font size (`setTextSize`)

Comment: if reduce ,i cannot view the text clearly.dynamically i added the text.

Comment: I am sorry you really have no other option, unless you are willing to resize the image to a bigger resolution..